# Typescript: Replace every occurrence loop. String manipulation loop

Tags: javascript, string, loops, typescript

I have a piece of code, which goal is to replace every occurence of @something with an anchor tag. The replacement itself works fine, the looping in general does not. Just consider this a string manipulation method, which has to find every occurence of something, then replace it with something else - but can't do replace all, since it depends on what comes after the '@' character.

Here is the code.

```
private generateAnchors(content: string) {
    let cutIndex = 0;
    let contentToReturn = content;
    let leftToAnalyze = content;
    if (leftToAnalyze.indexOf('@') !== -1) {
        while (true) {
            leftToAnalyze = content.substring(cutIndex);
            leftToAnalyze = leftToAnalyze.substring(content.indexOf('@'));
            let tag = leftToAnalyze.substring(leftToAnalyze.indexOf('@'), leftToAnalyze.indexOf(' ', leftToAnalyze.indexOf('@')));
            cutIndex += leftToAnalyze.indexOf(tag)+tag.length;
            let address = tag.substring(1, tag.length);
            let anchor = '<a href="/home/user/'+address+'">'+tag+'</a>';
            let newContentSubString = leftToAnalyze.replace(tag, anchor);
            contentToReturn = contentToReturn.replace(leftToAnalyze, newContentSubString);
            if (leftToAnalyze.indexOf('@') === -1) break;
        }
    }
    return contentToReturn;
}
```

in a small string like ' hello @JEDS & @Mill also @theHulk deserves a mention'
it works fine. However I found an occurrence with was a larger string, where the @ tag was in the end of the string, and it seemed like it was looping forever, and replacing stuff it weren't supposed too.

What am I overseeing in this piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in your `cutIndex` calculation. It looks up the index of `tag` in `leftToAnalyze` and uses that index into `content` at the beginning of the loop (i.e., `leftToAnalyze = content.substring(cutIndex)`), causing it to analyze the same text from the previous run.

`cutIndex` should actually be looking in `content`:

```
// cutIndex += leftToAnalyze.indexOf(tag)+tag.length;  // DON'T DO THIS
cutIndex += content.indexOf(tag)+tag.length;
```

In addition, the loop should bail early if `leftToAnalyze` is empty:

```
while (true) {
  leftToAnalyze = content.substring(cutIndex);
  const indexOfFirstAt = content.indexOf('@');
  leftToAnalyze = leftToAnalyze.substring(indexOfFirstAt);

  // nothing left? bail
  if (!leftToAnalyze) break;
  ...
}
```

```js
function generateAnchors(content) {
  let cutIndex = 0;
  let contentToReturn = content;
  let leftToAnalyze = content;
  if (leftToAnalyze.indexOf('@') !== -1) {
      let limit = 100;
      let i = 0;
      while (i++ < limit) {
          leftToAnalyze = content.substring(cutIndex);
          const indexOfFirstAt = content.indexOf('@');
          leftToAnalyze = leftToAnalyze.substring(indexOfFirstAt);
          if (!leftToAnalyze) break;
          const indexOfNextAt = leftToAnalyze.indexOf('@');
          const indexOfSpace = leftToAnalyze.indexOf(' ', indexOfNextAt);
          let tag = leftToAnalyze.substring(leftToAnalyze.indexOf('@'), indexOfSpace);
          cutIndex += content.indexOf(tag)+tag.length;
          let address = tag.substring(1, tag.length);
          let anchor = '<a href="/home/user/'+address+'">'+tag+'</a>';
          let newContentSubString = leftToAnalyze.replace(tag, anchor);
          contentToReturn = contentToReturn.replace(leftToAnalyze, newContentSubString);
          if (leftToAnalyze.indexOf('@') === -1) break;
      }
  }
  return contentToReturn;
}

const input = 'foo @bar baz @qux @ @@@@@';

const output = generateAnchors(input);
console.log(output);
```

But I recommend simplifying your code with regular expressions. This loop could actually be simplified into one line with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
return content.replace(/(@([^ @]+))/ig, '<a href="/home/user/$2">$1</a>');
```

```js
function generateAnchors(content) {
  return content.replace(/(@([^ @]+))/ig, '<a href="/home/user/$2">$1</a>');
}

const input = 'foo @bar baz @qux @ @@@@@';

const output = generateAnchors(input);
console.log(output);
```

*[Explanation of `/(@([^ @]+))/ig`](https://regex101.com/r/Eh0VKf/2)*

Comment: acutally this returns 'Hello <a href="/home/user/@something>@something</a> fs' where is should return Hello <a href="/home/user/something">@something</a> fs'. the @ Tag need to be removed, and there is a missing "

Comment: Adding the " is easily done with `return content.replace(/(@[^ @]+)/ig, '<a href="/home/user/$1">$1</a>');` but how do I remove the @ at the first occurrence? ($1)

Comment: @JonasPraem Ok, fixed. You'd use a second capture group to capture only the name. See updated answer.